# How to fetch product variant from MySQL

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions, product-variations

How to fetch product variant from table. How to apply MySQL query for this

> products

```
+----+--------------+
| id | product_name |
+----+--------------+
|  1 | IPhone       |
+----+--------------+
```

> product_variants

```
+----+------------+-----------------+
| id | product_id | product_variant |
+----+------------+-----------------+
|  1 |          1 | COLORS          |
|  2 |          1 | RAM             |
|  3 |          1 | STORAGE         |
+----+------------+-----------------+
```

> product_variant_options

```
+----+------------+-----------------+
| id | variant_id | product_variant |
+----+------------+-----------------+
|  1 |          1 | BLUE            |
|  2 |          1 | GOLD            |
|  3 |          2 | 8GB             |
|  4 |          2 | 12GB            |
|  5 |          3 | 64GB            |
|  6 |          3 | 128GB           |
+----+------------+-----------------+
```

**I want output like this**

> output

```
+----+------------+--------------+---------+------------+
| id | product_id | product_name | variant |  options   |
+----+------------+--------------+---------+------------+
|  1 |          1 | IPhone       | COLOR   | BLUE,GOLD  |
|  2 |          1 | IPhone       | RAM     | 8GB,12GB   |
|  3 |          1 | IPhone       | STORAGE | 64GB,128GB |
+----+------------+--------------+---------+------------+
```

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the DB data to try, but this should work

```
 SELECT 
    products.id, product_variants.product_id, products.product_name,
    product_variants.product_variant,
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(product_variant) FROM product_variant_options AS vo WHERE vo.variant_id = product_variants.id) AS options
 FROM
    products
    LEFT JOIN product_variants ON products.id = product_variants.product_id
```

Just join the products and the product_variants table and GROUP_CONCAT the options

Comment: Wouldn’t it be faster and even more easier to read to also left join the options instead of doing a subquery?

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff   He wanted the output as in the example table.  I you join to the product_variant_options table, you would get another line for each option.  It would be possible but you would need more manipulation on the backend

Comment: @JoeGalind No. not if you GROUP_CONCAT the options.

Answer (score -1):

I can provide another solution without sub-query:

```
select 
    pv.id id,
    p.id product_id, 
    product_name,
    pv.product_variant,
    group_concat(pvo.product_variant) variants
from products p
join product_variants pv on p.id = pv.product_id
join product_variant_options pvo on pvo.variant_id = pv.id
group by p.id, product_name, pv.id, pv.product_variant
;
```

[Share SQL code](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=d48a06f4ee1862d5911d41f1efad5468&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80)

Result:

```
+====+============+==============+=================+============+
| id | product_id | product_name | product_variant | variants   |
+====+============+==============+=================+============+
| 1  | 1          | IPhone       | COLORS          | BLUE,GOLD  |
+----+------------+--------------+-----------------+------------+
| 2  | 1          | IPhone       | RAM             | 8GB,12GB   |
+----+------------+--------------+-----------------+------------+
| 3  | 1          | IPhone       | STORAGE         | 64GB,128GB |
+----+------------+--------------+-----------------+------------+
```